# div position in differents screens

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have a problem in my web design assigment.

I can't make my 4 divs appear in a specific location in the screen.

Also need to mention that all of the 4 divs need to be overlap so I used z-index. But when I run my site on different screens the position always change although I used percents.

This is my css code (`welcome, register, login, game` are my div classes):

```
.welcome 
{

    position:absolute;
    top:28%;
    right:9%;
    width:960px;
    height:660px;
     z-index: 3;
}

.register 
{

    position:absolute;
    top:28%;
    right:9%;
    width:960px;
    height:660px;
     z-index: 2;

    }

.Login 
{

    position:absolute;
    top:28%;
    right:9%;
    width:960px;
    height:660px;
     z-index: 1;
}

.game 
{

    position:absolute;
    top:28%;
    right:9%;
    width:960px;
    height:660px;
     z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused on what you want the divs to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `top` and `left` properties only work for elements if these elements' (doesn't have to be direct) parent `position` is set to `relative`.

So you can either set `body { position: relative;}` or create a wrapper div around your 4 divs and set its position to relative.

Here is a fiddle with the code you need; you can position the elements however you wish, and the divs' margins will always be screensize-adapted.

http://jsbin.com/ogexev/1/edit

Note: I changed the width/ height properties a bit (divided by 3) to make them fit the screen.

- PS: If many elements have the same properties, you're better off specifying them in one class. That's why I added a class `.common` in the fiddle.

Comment: i create a wrapper div and i set it position to relative, now the divs are in the middle of the screen but instead of being overlap, they became sequential.

Comment: Wow sorry, I put the wrong link in the post, this is the correct one: http://jsbin.com/ogexev/1/edit . You can continue on this code; you'll see it works.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you use percent in top and right, because the 28% of top in 1200px monitor and 960px height monitor is not the same. You must add the four divs inside a div. Create a div as a wrapper and it will work same on all the monitors. Because it doesn't matter the size of the screen the top and right values are the same.

Comment: i create a wrapper div and i set it position to relative, now the divs are in the middle of the screen but instead of being overlap, they became sequential.